# Is there a way to factorize a multicheck function in C#?

Tags: c#

Let's say that I have a class that implements a lot of checking methods for a process. To validate the process, I need to perform every check available in the class. How can I factorize a validation method without the code looking too dirty?

Example :

```
public class VerificationMethods {
    public void CheckDuplicate() {

    }


    public void CheckTitle() {

    }

    // a hundred methods

   public void Validate(){
       CheckDuplicate()
       CheckTitle()

       // a hundred more methods
   }

}
```

Is there a better way to design this verification process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection to the rescue! It can get dirty too, though:

```
[Validation(Order = 1)]
public void CheckDuplicate(...)

[Validation(Order = 3)]
public void CheckTitle(...)

[Validation(Order = 2)]
public void CheckSubtitle(...)
```

And then you'll need to extract all methods annotated with `ValidationAttribute`, order them by `Order` and apply in turn to whatever piece of data you are validating.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have a name convention for you validation methods and use some result container between methods (in my example it is bool).
So, you would get something like this:

```
public class Test
{        
    public bool FirstValidation(bool value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public bool SecondValidation(bool value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public bool Validate()
    {
        return _validate(true);
    }

    private static Func<bool, bool> _validate;        

    public Test()
    {
        /*
        * You can easily change bool to some other type
        */

        _validate = ChainBuilderHelper.BuildValidationChain<bool>(this, method => method.Name.EndsWith("Validation"), b => !b);
    }        
}

public static class ChainBuilderHelper
{        
    public static Func<T, T> BuildValidationChain<T>(object obj, Func<MethodInfo, bool> methodSelector, Func<T, bool> exitCriteria)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetMethods()
            .Where(methodSelector)
            .Select(o => Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T>), obj, o))
            .Cast<Func<T, T>>()
            .Aggregate((func, func1) => Compose(func, b => !exitCriteria(b) ? b : func1(b)));
    }        

    private static Func<TX, TZ> Compose<TX, TY, TZ>(Func<TX, TY> f, Func<TY, TZ> g)
    {
        return x => g(f(x));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var instance = new Test();
var result = instance.Validate();
```